# markerClusterer in AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am having a project which is displaying google map with a set of markers. But when i tried to add markerClusterer in my controller.js. The project does not compile and the console throws an error:

> markerClusterer is not defined

I have referenced markerClusterer's library in html and I am using angular. Does any one have experience using markerClusterer with angular?

Comment: post some code please.

Comment: I've used MarkerClusterer in an Angular project last year. It worked fine. You should include the relevant bits of code or create a Plnkr or JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue using [tombatossals' angular-leaflet directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive). The examples feature markerCluster, although the dependency is not included. You have to load [markerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) as an additional library, and you should be good. The page has instructions on how to do that.

Comment: hi Martin, i ended up using [angular google map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) and use angular service to instantiate the library. Thanks for looking into this problem!

Comment: The answer will help the next person, then.